# Finding an integrating factor for $(3t + \frac{6}{y})dt + (\frac{t^2}{y} + \frac{3y}{t})dy = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integrating-factor

I want to solve the differential equation

$$
\begin{equation}
(3t + \frac{6}{y})dt + (\frac{t^2}{y} + \frac{3y}{t})dy = 0\
\end{equation}
$$

using an integrating factor of the form $t^a y^b$ in order to make it exact, where

$$
M(t, y) = 3t + \frac{6}{y},\\
N(t, y) = \frac{t^2}{y} + \frac{3y}{t}.
$$

So we want

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial y} (t^ay^bM) &= \frac{\partial}{\partial t} (t^ay^bN)\\
b t^a y^{b-1} M+ t^ay^b \frac{\partial}{\partial y}M  &= at^{a-1}y^bN + t^a y^b \frac{\partial}{\partial t}N.
\end{align}
$$

By susbtituting

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial y}M &= -\frac{6}{y^2} \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}N &= \frac{2t}{y} - \frac{3y}{t^2},
\end{align}
$$

I arrived at

$$
3b + 6(b-1)t^{-1}y^{-1} = (a+2) + 3(a-1)t^{-3}y^{2}.
$$

But how do I find the values of $a$ and $b$ from here?

(Also, if my calculations could be verified, I'd really appreciate it!)

**Edit #1:** Apparently, on the last line, I had arrived at $(a+1)$, when in fact it should have been $(a+2)$.

Comment: Still, it is not exact. It becomes $\frac{\partial}{\partial y} M = -\frac{6t}{y^2}$ and $ \frac{\partial}{\partial t} N = \frac{3t^2}{y} $.

Comment: **Hint:** Oops, I meant multiply by $$t ~y.$$

Comment: It becomes exact! But how do we arrive at $ty$ if we could not guess it?

Comment: I don't think there's a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I rederive your equations everything Iooks good until your last line.  Then I find:

$3b+6(b-1)t^{-1}y^{-1}=(a+2)+3(a-1)t^{-3}y^2$

Initially you had $a+1$ instead of $a+2$ missing a factor of 2 in one of your terms; now corrected.

Now we argue that the terms with unlike powers of $t$ and $y$ on the left and right sides must be zeroed out, forcing $a=b=1$; then this must be checked by verifying the remaining terms are equal.  Only if this checking step works do you have an integrating factor with the assumed form; if it doesn't work you need a different integrating factor.  Here, $3b=a+2$ works.  Thereby $ty$ is proved an integrating factor.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But how is it guaranteed that when _"we argue that the terms with unlike powers of t and y on the left and right sides must be zeroed out"_ we get acceptable values for $a$ and $b$? I mean, If by your method we arrived at a contradiction (like it would have been by my wrong computation of $a+1$), could we argue that $t^a y^b$ could *not* be an integrating factor for this equation, for any value of $a, b$? Or is it we should keep looking?

Comment: Yes, but it's still not clear to me why if the test of  _zeroing out the terms with unlike powers of t and y on the left and right sides_ fails, how do can we be sure that $t^a y^b$ could not be an integrating factor, for any $a, b$? I mean maybe there are such $a$s and $b$s and it's just that this test failed to 'reveal' them.

Comment: No.  You were covering all possible combinations of $a$ and $b$.  If you don't find one that meets all the equality requirements, you just plain don't have an integrating factor with the form $t^ay^b$ and you have to try something else.  I assume this is a textbook problem and it was "rigged" to have a relatively simple integrating factor.

Comment: Yes, but still, the question remains, why or how are we covering all possible combinations of $a$ and $b$ this way?

Comment: Your best approach, after rendering the equation derived above, is to see what happens if you try $(a,b)$ with values other than $(1,1)$.  You get an equation that does not hold VC for all $t$ and $y$ and that means you didn't render the differential equation exact for all $t$ and $y$.  Only by finding values of $a$ and $b$ at the end which remove all the unlike terms and properly balance the rest can you get an integrating factor ofvthe form you assume, and I show that $(1,1)$ is the only combination that passes.

Comment: I think I got it. So what you are saying could be stated somehow like this: _Bring what I write on the last line in the form $ (a+2-3b) - 6(b-1)t^{-1}y^{-1} + 3(a-1)t^{-3}y^2 = 0 $ and argue that since we want it to be identically equal to zero, no matter what the values of $t$ and $y$ are, and since $1, t^{-1}y^{-1}, t^{-3}y^2$ are linearly independent, then it must be that their coefficients are equal to zero. Thus $a = b = 1$._  Are we saying the same thing?

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different approach to this problem. In the first place, notice that

\begin{align*}
3t + \frac{6}{y} + \left(\frac{t^{2}}{y} + \frac{3y}{t}\right)y^{\prime} = 0
\end{align*}

As suggested by Moo, multiply it by $ty$ in order to obtain
\begin{align*}
3t^{2}y + 6t + (t^{3} + 3y^{2})y^{\prime} = 0
\end{align*}

Then we can rearrange it as
\begin{align*}
(3t^{2}y + t^{3}y^{\prime}) + 3y^{2}y^{\prime} + 6t = 0 \Longleftrightarrow (t^{3}y)^{\prime} + (y^{3})^{\prime} + 6t = 0
\end{align*}

After integration, it becomes
\begin{align*}
t^{3}y + y^{3} + 3t^{2} + k =0
\end{align*}

which is a cubic in the dependent variable $y$.

Comment: How is that integrating factor found, though?  The OP apparently does not have ESP.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But as @OscarLanzi said, I'm interested in the way of finding an integrating factor for the equation.